# Where is ContentWidget.CwConstants located and what is it?

Tags: gwt, widget

I´ve just started learning GWT and I´m trying to implement http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwFileUpload and but failing miserably.

Where is the ContentWidget.CwConstants suppose to come from and what exactly is it?

```
public static interface CwConstants extends Constants,
      ContentWidget.CwConstants {
    String cwFileUploadButton();

    String cwFileUploadDescription();

    String cwFileUploadName();

String cwFileUploadNoFileError();

String cwFileUploadSelectFile();

    String cwFileUploadSuccessful();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the source tree of the samples in the GWT code project. There you also find the class you are looking for: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/showcase/src/com/google/gwt/sample/showcase/client/ContentWidget.java

Comment: Do you know how to download all the branch?

Comment: You can checkout the code via subversion, that way you get all files at once. The following command will checkout only the showcase example in a directory called gwt-showcase. `svn checkout http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/showcase gwt-showcase`. See also http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/checkout for more information on getting the gwt source.

Comment: I have this as response: 
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\New folder>svn checkout http://google-web-toolkit.g
ooglecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/showcase gwt-showcase
svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://google-web-toolki
t.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/showcase'
svn: E175002: OPTIONS of 'http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/sam
ples/showcase': Could not resolve hostname `google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com':
No such host is known.
 (http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com)

Comment: Not sure what the problem might be. In your call I miss `http://`, if you didn't add it, it might be the problem. I checked the command in my comment and it works.

Comment: hm... I am using svn 1.7.7  It always shows unresolved host-name, but the same link can be opened through the browser! strange!